# Navgrid refresh button does nothing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that when I click the refresh button, it does nothing. No request made to the server. But I can see it executing the beforeRequest() function. Anyone knows what is going on?

```
jQuery("#paramlistFlex").jqGrid({
    url: root + mod + '/setlistview',
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:[' ', 'Name of Set', 'Description of Set', 'Date of Set'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'myac', width:50, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', formatoptions:{keys:true, editbutton : false, delbutton : false, delOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false},editOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false}}},
        {name:'set_name',index:'set_name', width:200},
        {name:'set_desc',index:'set_desc', width:400},
        {name:'set_date',index:'set_date', width:200}
        ],
    width: $('.body').width()-25,
    height: ($('.body').height()-240)/2,
    pager: '#pagerFlex2',
    sortname: 'set_id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl: root + mod + '/detailpost',
    caption:"Set of Parameter List",
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        activedf = "#paramlistFlex";
    },
    afterInsertRow: function () {
        var grid = $(this),
        iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'myac'); // 'act' - name of the actions column
        grid.find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
        .each(function() {
            if ($(this).find(">div>div").length == 2)
            {
                $("<div>",
                    {
                        title: "Delete",
                        mouseover: function() {
                            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseout: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        click: function(e) {
                            df_delete_1($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                  ).css({float:"left"})
                   .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
                   .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>')
                   .prependTo($(this).children("div"));


            }
        });
    },
    beforeRequest: function() {
        var setid = $('input[name=item]').val();
        if (setid == "")
            setid = 0;

        jQuery("#paramlistFlex").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:{setid: setid}});
        console.log('hiya');
    }
});

jQuery("#paramlistFlex").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerFlex2',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:false});
jQuery("#paramlistFlex").jqGrid('gridResize', {minWidth:350, maxWidth:1920, minHeight:80, maxHeight:1080} );
```

Comment: I think datatype: "local" makes only one request to the server, then using cache data, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `datatype: "local"` in the grid. It's unclear from the code which you posed how you fill jqGrid. If you use `addRowData` for filling you should know that it's the slowest way of filling the local grid.

The `url` parameter will be ignored in case of `datatype: "local"` and the reloading of the grid will be done with the *local data*. For example if you was on the second page or if the data was filtered the filter will be reset and the page number will be 1. If you want to load the data *from the server* you have to change `datatype` to `"json"` or to `"xml"` with respect of `setGridParam` before trigger "reloadGrid" event.